# Determine Radius of Convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^{k^m}}{k!}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I am trying to determine the radius of convergence for the series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^{k^m}}{k!}\qquad(m\in \mathbb{N})$$
with no success.

I tried to used the root test to determine it but since the radius of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^{k}}{k!}$ is $\infty$, I got $\infty/\infty$.

Any answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m=1$ it the series of $e^z$ with radius of convergence $\infty$. Let $m\ge2$.
$$
\frac{\dfrac{|z|^{(k+1)^m}}{(k+1)!}}{\dfrac{|z|^{k^m}}{k!}}=\frac{|z|^{(k+1)^m-k^m}}{k+1}.
$$
As $k\to\infty$, this converges to $0$ if $|z|\le1$ and to $\infty$ if $|z|>1$, so that the radius of convergence is $1$.